# Rails5, ActiveJob rescue_from not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activejob, rescue

I am trying to reproduce this example code: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveJob/Enqueuing/retry_job but I don't manage to make the `rescue_from` working in an ActiveJob

#### Steps to reproduce

I have prepared a test project:

- https://github.com/fguillen/TestingActiveJobRescueFrom

#### Expected behavior

In this Job:

- https://github.com/fguillen/TestingActiveJobRescueFrom/blob/master/app/jobs/test_job_job.rb

I am expecting to see the `rescue_from` message when I perform the Job:

```
irb(main):005:0> TestJobJob.perform_now
```

#### Actual behavior

Instead of the message I see the Exception been propagated:

```
irb(main):004:0> TestJobJob.perform_now
Performing TestJobJob from Async(default)
Performed TestJobJob from Async(default) in 0.82ms
Exception: This is the error message
    from /Users/fguillen/Development/Temp/TestingActiveJobRescueFrom/app/jobs/test_job_job.rb:9:in `perform'
    from /Users/fguillen/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activejob-5.0.2/lib/active_job/execution.rb:34:in `block in perform_now'
    from /Users/fguillen/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
    from /Users/fguillen/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
    from /Users/fguillen/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
    from /Users/fguillen/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:448:in `block (2 levels) in around'
    from /Users/fguillen/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:286:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
    from /Users/fguillen/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/i18n-0.8.1/lib/i18n.rb:257:in `with_locale'
```

Same behaviour when I try to reproduce the issue in a test:

- https://github.com/fguillen/TestingActiveJobRescueFrom/blob/master/test/jobs/test_job_job_test.rb

#### System configuration

**Rails version**: 5.0.2
**Ruby version**: 2.3.1p112

Comment: Issue in Rails tracker: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/28874

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As opposed of the `ActionController::Base.rescue_from` behaviour which actually captures any `Exception`:

```
class MyTestsController < ApplicationController
  rescue_from Exception do |exception|
    render plain: "Rescuing the exception: '#{exception}'", status: 500
  end

  def raise_exception
    raise Exception.new("This is an Exception")
  end

  def raise_standard_error
    raise StandardError.new("This is an StandardError")
  end
end
```

[Example code](https://github.com/fguillen/TestingActiveJobRescueFrom/commit/fdbb58bd1bd9e7a1e0b90953d318b8aacddb248c)

`ActiveJob::Base.rescue_from` only captures classes inheriting from `StandardError`:

```
class TestJob2Job < ApplicationJob
  rescue_from Exception do |exception|
    Rails.logger.info "I am on rescue_from: #{exception}"
  end

  def perform(*args)
    raise StandardError.new("This is the error message")
  end
end
```

[Example code](https://github.com/fguillen/TestingActiveJobRescueFrom/commit/2ea74ebfe240cd9e226912f98e4f73e1974cbf55)

You can see the conversation with the maintainers here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/28874#issuecomment-297599254